# Bluetooth periodically switches off

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

The Bluetooth on my Android phone periodically switches off.

This is a problem because I've attached a "Tile" to my keys. To find my keys using my phone, and my phone using my keys. And after the Bluetooth switches off, this doesn't work.

- phone: Xiaomi Max 2
- Android version: 7.1.1
- MIUI version: 11.0.2.0

The best advice I've gleaned from the internet so far has been to give the "Bluetooth Share" app all the permissions it needs. This seems to have lengthened the time it takes before the Bluetooth switches off.

[image]

---

**Thoughts? Suggestions?**

Comment: Do you like to keep your Bluetooth (BT) always on? If yes, the workaround for your problem is to use an automation app that can enable BT whenever it detects that BT was switched off. Otherwise, you would want to list apps which have BT permission in your device and use trial and error by removing BT change permission on each one of them and see if that solves the issue. A technical option is to use logcat but I am not sure how much it would help.

Comment: @Firelord Awesome idea... it didn't occur to me that such an automation app existed... if you know of any please share... otherwise I'm going to google around and find something regardless... Thanks.

Comment: You can use [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). It is easy to use and the first run would guide you how to use it. Trigger: Bluetooth Off, Action: Bluetooth On, Constraint: None. Make sure to exempt MacroDroid from Battery optimization.

Comment: I would assume the BT app is getting killed. This is because of the aggressive battery saving by Xiomi: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Comment: @Robert Thanks!

Comment: Just an update. I'm using an app called "Bluetooth Always On", and it works.